# What are the rules to this "CheeseGame"?

Tags: identify-this-game

I was treasure hunting through a second-hand shop that imports most of its items from Japan and I found this wooden game.

Pieces:
5 Natural-colored Cheese Wedges
1 Yellow Cheese Wedge
1 Mouse
1 Dome Base Board (?)

It did not come with original box and there are no other branding on any of the pieces other than what I'm assuming is the base or board of the game as you can see in the first image below, with the words "CheeseGame". But there is a distinct small white X on the mouse's cheek.

I'm not sure if I have all of the pieces because when I line up the cheese wedges on the "board", there is a perfect gap for two more wedges. (seen in second image)

The base is a wooden dome that I am assuming is placed upside down so that the rounded bottom creates the stage for a balancing game. The third image turns this base upside down to show it clearly.

Can anyone help identify this? I'm usually quite good at internet sleuthing, but no luck so far.

[image: CheeseGame image1]

[image: CheeseGame image2]

[image: CheeseGame image3]

Comment: for a little context: https://www.biccamera.com/bc/item/1414786/

Comment: @npst That was SUPER helpful! Confirms 6 cheese total and provides the company name. So I tracked them down and found their active facebook page with an email. Fingers crossed they respond with game rules!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @npst for the tip on the Japanese manufacturer's name, which lead to contacting them directly and receiving a response on the rules of the game!

Here is what they wrote back:

> Thank you for your inquiry.
>   The image you have attached is "Balance Game" of our product "Cheese Game".
>   This is a wooden toy that also becomes an interior, and the contents are 7 pieces of cheese, 1 mouse and 1 base.
>
> The attached PDF data is a guidance sheet enclosed with the product.
>   Stack the cheese and the rat on the base so as not to collapse.
>   There is no particular rule.
>   Please try various stacking methods and enjoy.

Here is the image that comes with the game to explain the rules (in Japanese). But the image at least suggests some pretty interesting stacking options.

[image]

Not sure what they meant by "also becomes an interior", maybe "interior decoration"? Because I have been playing with it as a desk toy and it works well for that.

So, not an actual 2 player game as I was hoping but fun none-the-less, and glad to have been able to solve the mystery. Thanks to all who attempted to track this down.